# Redirect one blog to the other (SO&SE)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, blog

I remember a few days (?) ago the SE blog redirected to the SO blog, but now they both seem to be mirroring the same content. This is especially confusing because the logo is for SE and points to the SE URI and the blog permalinks point to the SO one.

[image: The StackExchange logo on the blog]

It would be less confusing if the logo was for SO and the SE blog redirected to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design -- both domains point to the same blog.